# Using window.location.replace(), is it possible to show on the location bar the web domain instead of the html loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, blogger

I'm using the javascript code below on a blogger template to load an html file located on Google Drive:

```
window.location.replace("http://googledrive.com/host/.../1.html");
```

When you go to the blogger domain www.webdomain.com the location bar of the browser changes to the long and ugly url of Google Drive (http://googledrive.com/host/.../1.html) which is not perfect for the web user. I wonder if it's possible to keep the blogger address all the time on the location bar using some kind of javascript (or whatever code) on Blogger or inside the html hosted in GDrive.

I know that using an iframe would be a solution for this, but that option has given me lots of headaches so that's why I trying this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you ask isn't really possible unless you use your iframe method. If you could it would be a pretty serious security exploit for spoofing.

Comment: Thank you. I had the feeling that would be the problem...